# XAConnectionFactory not bound in jboss

Tags: jsp, servlets, jboss, ejb

I have application developed using EJB and jsp servlet I have used message driven bean to upload batch in bulk while starting process in batch i got following error.

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Error creating the dlq connection: XAConnectionFactory not bound
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.jms.DLQHandler.createService(DLQHandler.java:171)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalCreate(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:237)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.create(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:164)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.jms.JMSContainerInvoker.innerCreate(JMSContainerInvoker.java:542)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.jms.JMSContainerInvoker.startService(JMSContainerInvoker.java:764)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:271)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.ReflectedDispatcher.dispatch(ReflectedDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:62)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:54)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:82)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:197)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:473)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:884)
    at $Proxy2294.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:414)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.ReflectedDispatcher.dispatch(ReflectedDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:62)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:54)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:82)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:197)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:473)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.start(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:170)
    at org.jboss.ejb.MessageDrivenContainer.startService(MessageDrivenContainer.java:234)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:271)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.ReflectedDispatcher.dispatch(ReflectedDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:62)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:54)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:82)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:197)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:473)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:884)
    at $Proxy18.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:414)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.ReflectedDispatcher.dispatch(ReflectedDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:62)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:54)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:82)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:197)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:473)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
    at $Proxy2214.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb.EjbModule.startService(EjbModule.java:367)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:271)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.ReflectedDispatcher.dispatch(ReflectedDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:62)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:54)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:82)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:197)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:473)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:884)
    at $Proxy18.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:414)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.ReflectedDispatcher.dispatch(ReflectedDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:62)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:54)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:82)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:197)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:473)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
    at $Proxy15.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb.EJBDeployer.start(EJBDeployer.java:570)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:829)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:821)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:641)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:604)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.ReflectedDispatcher.dispatch(ReflectedDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:62)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:54)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:82)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:197)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:473)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
    at $Proxy8.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:304)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:478)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:201)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:274)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:271)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.ReflectedDispatcher.dispatch(ReflectedDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:62)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:54)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:82)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:197)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:473)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:884)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:414)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.ReflectedDispatcher.dispatch(ReflectedDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:62)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:54)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:82)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:197)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:473)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
    at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:251)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:829)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:641)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:604)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:588)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.ReflectedDispatcher.dispatch(ReflectedDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:62)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:54)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:82)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:197)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:473)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
    at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:407)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:311)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:145)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:399)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Please help me and guide me why this error take place ?

Comment: I have deleted data,temp and log folder from jboss and restart it , surprisingly it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably a human error.

Please look at the following references

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/IGetXAConnectionFactoryNotBoundHowDoIFixIt
https://community.jboss.org/thread/47033